# Improve sql query (JPA?)

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql, jpa

I don't know enough about sql to improve a database query.

I have the following native sql query:

```
SELECT 
   m.id, 
   m.merchantname, 
   date_trunc('month' ,to_timestamp(t.timestamp / 1000)) as month_name,
   COUNT(*) as num_transactions, 
   cast(SUM(case when t.type IN('VEND_READER','VEND_READER_COUPON_TRANSFER') THEN t.amount ELSE 0 END) as numeric) AS sum_vend, 
   cast(SUM(case when t.type IN('REVALUE_READER','REVALUE_STARTBALANCE','REVALUE_PAYPAL','REVALUE_PROMOTION','REVALUE_CREDITCARD') THEN t.amount ELSE 0 END) AS numeric) as sum_revalue 

FROM 
   transaction t JOIN merchant m ON m.id = t.merchant_id 

WHERE 
   t.transactionstate = 'SUCCESS' 
GROUP BY 
   m.id, month_name  
ORDER BY
   m.id
```

**All I want are entries including sum of vends/revaluations and count of transactions for every merchant and month.**

It doesn't matter how the *month* field is formatted (It could be as sql timestamp or string or ...)

```
[
 {merchantID:1, merchantName:"myMerchant", vend:2030, revalue:1980, transactions:115, month:"July - 2016"},
 {merchantID:1, merchantName:"myMerchant", vend:1895, revalue:2700, transactions:100, month:"June - 2016"},
 {merchantID:1, merchantName:"myMerchant", vend:2453, revalue:1892, transactions:120, month:"May - 2016"},
 {merchantID:2, merchantName:"myMerchant2", vend:345, revalue:360, transactions:123, month:"July - 2016"},
 ...
]
```

If such a query is possible with JPA it would be great. But I couldn't find a way to convert an epoch time in miliseconds to an month. All our timestamps(miliseconds since 1970) are saved as BIGINT.

Merchant.java

```
@Entity
public class Merchant
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private Integer merchantGlobalID;

    private String merchantName;
}
```

Transaction.java

```
@Entity
public class Transaction
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Merchant merchant;

    private Integer amount;

    private Long timestamp;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private TransactionType type;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private TransactionState transactionState;
}
```

My query works, but it has a really bad performance. We use a postgres database and the current query use some specific commands. If there is a way to get the results in JPA it would be nice.

**EDIT:**

On advice of [Robe Elckers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/557470/robe-elckers) I call an `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` query. Here are the results. I don't know what I should do now.

```
GroupAggregate  (cost=797050.04..849223.46 rows=1070224 width=559) (actual time=6913.003..7368.277 rows=16 loops=1)
  Group Key: m.id, (date_trunc('month'::text, to_timestamp(((t."timestamp" / 1000))::double precision)))
  ->  Sort  (cost=797050.04..799725.60 rows=1070224 width=559) (actual time=6792.567..7049.720 rows=1070341 loops=1)
        Sort Key: m.id, (date_trunc('month'::text, to_timestamp(((t."timestamp" / 1000))::double precision)))
        Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 57384kB
        ->  Hash Join  (cost=4.61..155797.88 rows=1070224 width=559) (actual time=0.104..6005.352 rows=1070341 loops=1)
              Hash Cond: (t.merchant_id = m.id)
              ->  Seq Scan on transaction t  (cost=0.00..130375.45 rows=1070224 width=32) (actual time=0.006..3502.850 rows=1070341 loops=1)
                    Filter: ((transactionstate)::text = 'SUCCESS'::text)
                    Rows Removed by Filter: 1598
              ->  Hash  (cost=4.27..4.27 rows=27 width=535) (actual time=0.023..0.023 rows=27 loops=1)
                    Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 2kB
                    ->  Seq Scan on merchant m  (cost=0.00..4.27 rows=27 width=535) (actual time=0.004..0.015 rows=27 loops=1)
Planning time: 0.535 ms
Execution time: 7373.833 ms
```

Comment: I cannot imagine better performance by rewriting to JPQL. I think you should focus on optimizing your native query by analyzing it using 'explain analyze'. Perhaps you are missing some indexes?

Comment: @Robe. Thank you for your reply. I will check that, I don't think that the indexes are the problem. I think that there are faster way to convert my data(sum, count, milliseconds -> month,...). But I don't have enough expirience...

Comment: You might try an index on `transaction(transactionstate, merchant_id)` and to increase `work_mem`, currently the grouping is done on disk.

Comment: The index doesn't have som visible effect. But the increase of `work_mem` saved about a second. Thanks...